# Using image dimensions from a URL without loading it onto page - Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm currently learning JavaScript in a bootcamp and I'm having a hard time figuring out how to solve a problem. I have googled it extensively, but I feel like I'm missing a core piece of functionality in what I'm trying to do.

I'm getting an array of returned images from an API based on a date specified by a date selector. I want to measure the dimensions of the natural height and width of each item in the array and filter them into another array which I will use to display a gallery. Here is a link to what the API returns:

[API returned object array index[0] example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qXVnd.png)

Here is the relevant piece of code, including the API call.

```
    spaceApp.getRoverPhotos = (date) => {
        $.ajax({
            url: spaceApp.roverUrl,
            method: 'GET',
            data: {
                api_key: spaceApp.key,
                earth_date: date,
                camera: spaceApp.cameras,
                page: 1,
            }
        }).then((res) => {

            //functioning code but doesn't wait for stuff to load.
            let displayArray = res.photos.filter( (each) => {  
                let imageDim = new Image();
                imageDim.src = each.img_src;    
                if(imageDim.naturalWidth >= 1000 && imageDim.naturalHeight >= 1000) {
                    return true;
                }
                else {
                    return false;
                }
            });
            console.log(displayArray);
        })
    }
```

The results of this are not consistent, and I think it's the way that the images are being loaded. The filter method is used after a successful promise, so I know that the array consistently returns the information I need, but I don't always get the natural height and width because of the way something is loading. I used a forEach to console log the natural height and width when I submit the date twice in a row. The first returns me no values, the second has them all loaded:

[First submit, 25 results of 0 0, then all show upon re-submitting the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDiGs.png)

My best guess is this has something to do with caching the images. I've tried to use `image.onload` in creative ways, but I'm not sure that makes sense, given that I haven't used them on the page anywhere(similarly, I tried `imageDim.addEventHandler('load', ()=>{}))`. I have tried using map to create a new array of images using the new Image() approach above, and then filtering the new array, but I ran into the same issue. I have considered using a promise, but I can't figure out how to "load" images without displaying them on the page, and using that as a promise inside a filter.

I have seen, and tried without success, a few variations of this:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function() { alert("Height: " + this.height); }
img.src = "http://path/to/image.jpg";
```

I'm sorry if I'm missing a step here, but I've been working on this for several hours without success. I've asked my only senior developer friend for help, but he wasn't able to provide me much guidance since he happened to not be at home at the time (he suggested I "load" the images into a new array, then filter, but I have the same problem of how to make an image load - I did attempt his suggestion).

If anyone could spare the time to help me I would really appreciate it! I feel I'm at a roadblock because I don't quite know the nature of the true problem I'm experiencing, if someone can tell me what I'm missing I can continue googling it! Thank you in advance!

Comment: try including `setInterval()` loop after `imageDim.src = each.img_src;` and run the loop until `imageDim.complete` returns true.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This is a well-written question so thank you but please avoid sending screenshots of code or data! People want to copy-paste your code onto their machines to play with it and try to fix it. If you give them screenshots, they can't do that, probably won't want to bother typing it out themselves, and will instead simply write a welcoming but unhelpful comment like this one ;)

Comment: If the data is showing up late but exists, then it sounds like it's an asynchronous problem. Also, you should add a return statement to your ajax call

Comment: Hi GKFX, thanks for the welcome! Sorry, I'm not aware of best practices, I only included screenshots of some results because I thought that may make things clearer on what data I'm working on (so a person can make sure there isn't an error in the data), and a console log showing the different results I'm seeing. I will avoid this in the future!! Thank you for the advice :)

Comment: Check out:  https://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/

Using .then, your ajax request is either resolved, rejected or still in progress. The key part being 'still in progress'. This could cause issues where your code would be executing faster than your ajax calls. Take a look into asynchronous calls and promises